# SQL: Join tables with values extracted from a select SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that includes a full name of users, like:

```
Blagg, Eli D.
Do, Danny
Foley, Charles E. Jr
.....
```

Using this SQL gives me the values in first and last names only.

```
select concat(vl.lastname, vf.firstname)
from UserName as t cross apply
 (values (left(t.name, charindex(', ', t.name)), stuff(t.name, 1, 
charindex(', ', t.name) + 1, ''))) vl(lastname, rest) 
cross apply 
(values (left(vl.rest, charindex(' ', vl.rest + ' ')))) vf(firstname)
```

Can I use the values to join with another table, like:

```
select b.name, a.LName, a.FName, a.MI
from NewRecruit a
left join UserName b on (b.name =(
select concat(vl.lastname, vf.firstname)
from contact1379 as t cross apply
(values (left(t.name, charindex(', ', t.name)), stuff(t.name, 1, 
charindex(', ', t.name) + 1, ''))) vl(lastname, rest) cross apply
(values (left(vl.rest, charindex(' ', vl.rest + ' ')))) vf(firstname)
)
)
= 
(a.LName + ',' +  a.FName)
```

There is an error with '='...

Comment: What happens with double-barrel names like `Aaronson-Arnold, Aaron-Angus Jr`? And what about names like `Hammer, M C`, and `Jameson, J Jonah`?

Comment: The names are always in "last name", "first name" and "middle initial" type of format, with some names missing the middle initials. And the first names aren't in a one-letter format.  There are a few last names with hyphens.

Comment: Add Malcolm McDowell, Conan O'Brien, Jonathan Rhys-Davies  and Carl van der Walt to your sample data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such string processing is painful in SQL Server.  I find that using `apply` multiple times helps:

```
select concat(vl.lastname, vf.firstname)
from (values ('Foley, Charles E. Jr'),
             ('Blagg, Eli D.'),
             ('Do, Danny')
     ) v(name) cross apply
     (values (left(name, charindex(', ', name)), stuff(name, 1, charindex(', ', name) + 1, ''))) vl(lastname, rest) cross apply
     (values (left(rest, charindex(' ', rest + ' ')))) vf(firstname);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=79f2b2416b1d508c38f8ce2870aefae1) is the db<>fiddle.

Unfortunately, `string_split()` is not appropriate because it does not return the order of the substrings.  Other `split()` functions sometimes have this functionality, and hopefully it will appear in the future.

EDIT:

You can update the values in the table with:

```
update t
    set name = concat(vl.lastname, vf.firstname)
from t cross apply
     (values (left(t.name, charindex(', ', t.name)), stuff(t.name, 1, charindex(', ', t.name) + 1, ''))) vl(lastname, rest) cross apply
     (values (left(vl.rest, charindex(' ', vl.rest + ' ')))) vf(firstname);
```

I would advise you to test the logic or backup the table before running the update.

Comment: This is great! But is there a way to incorporate this into a join with another table? Like, if I run the SQL listed above in my question, I can get the values with first and last names only.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query to retrieve the first and last name using regular expression.

```
SELECT full, REGEXP_REPLACE(full, '([a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z,]+)([-\'\\s][a-zA-Z]+)','FIRST:\\1  LAST:\\3') FROM names;
FROM names;
```